# Invalid Lexical Value for Attribute Valuewith Whitespace in Range Path Index in MarkLogic

Tags: marklogic

Given the following HTML document:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <meta name="foo" content="bar" />
    <meta name="another item" content="12345" />
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

I created a range-path-index targeting the `<meta name="foo" content="bar" />` `@content` value:

```
    {
        "scalar-type": "string",
        "collation": "http://marklogic.com/collation/en/S1",
        "range-value-positions": false,
        "invalid-values": "reject",
        "path-expression": "/*:html/*:head/*:meta[@name='foo']/@content"
    }
```

However, I am getting the following error whenever the xpath `/*:html/*:head/*:meta[@name='foo']` is evaluated:

> [1.0-ml] XDMP-LEXVAL: xs:NMTOKEN("another item") -- Invalid lexical
>   value "another item"

For example:

`fn:doc('/test/test.xhtml')/*:html/*:head/*:meta[@name='foo']`

It will also prevent new documents with the same structure from being ingested (due to "invalid-values": "reject").

I don't understand where the error comes from. It seems if I remove white spaces from all meta tag names, it would work. But that is not a practical solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect the issue is caused by a **different** `meta` tag, one with `'another item'` as value of the `name` attribute.

The official XHTML schema says that the `content` attribute can contain any string, but the `name` attribute is a so-called `xs:NMTOKEN`. xs:NMTOKEN does not allow whitespace in the value.

Your path expression accesses the `name` attribute of `meta` tags. MarkLogic needs to extract the value of that attribute to be able to compare it with your `'foo'` string. However, MarkLogic has a number of XML Schemas of common standards pre-loaded. It recognizes the namespace, and attempts to pull up a typed value based on the official Schema, and will complain if the value does not comply.

I think you have a few options:

- use valid name attribute values (might be out of your control)
- strip off the xhtml namespace (sounds like overkill)
- edit the path expression to explicitly cast the name value to a string, using something like: `*:meta[string(@name)='foo']/@content`

Note: path index expressions don't need to start at the root of a document. You could think of them as match patterns in XSLT.

HTH!

Comment: Hey, @grtjn. Thanks for the explanation! This is exactly what I was looking for.